# xslt merge multiple nodes with same name

Tags: xslt, merge, element

I can see many answers to similar questions, but I can't seem to get them work for me. I have some xml files with some sibling element nodes having same tag name. I want to merge these nodes using XSLT. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Screen>
  <Shapes>
    <Triangle id="tri1">
    <color>red</color>
    <size>large</size>
    </Triangle>
  </Shapes>
  <Shapes>
    <Rectangle id="rec1">
      <color>blue</color>
      <size>medium</size>
    </Rectangle>
  </Shapes>
  <Shapes>
    <Circle id="cir1">
      <color>green</color>
      <size>small</size>
    </Circle>
  </Shapes>
  <Shapes>
    <Square id="sqr1">
      <color>yellow</color>
      <size>large</size>
    </Square>
  </Shapes>
  <Device>
    <Name>peg</Name>
    <type>X11</type>
  </Device>
  <Utilities>
    <Software>QT</Software>
    <Platform>Linux</Platform>
  </Utilities>
</Screen>
```

I want to merge all "Shapes" nodes. 
**Required Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Screen>
  <Shapes>
    <Triangle id="tri1">
      <color>red</color>
      <size>large</size>
    </Triangle>

    <Rectangle id="rec1">
      <color>blue</color>
      <size>medium</size>
    </Rectangle>

    <Circle id="cir1">
      <color>green</color>
      <size>small</size>
    </Circle>

    <Square id="sqr1">
      <color>yellow</color>
      <size>large</size>
    </Square>
  </Shapes>
  <Device>
    <Name>peg</Name>
    <type>X11</type>
  </Device>
  <Utilities>
    <Software>QT</Software>
    <Platform>Linux</Platform>
  </Utilities>
</Screen>
```

XSLT I tried was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="Shapes">
    <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::*[local-name() = 'Shapes'])">

      <Shapes>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[local-name() = 'Shapes']" />
      </Shapes>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::*[local-name() = 'Shapes']">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the output I got was ( :( )

```
<Screen>
<Shapes>
    <Triangle id="tri1">
      <color>red</color>
      <size>large</size>
    </Triangle>

    <Rectangle id="rec1">
      <color>blue</color>
      <size>medium</size>
    </Rectangle>

    <Circle id="cir1">
      <color>green</color>
      <size>small</size>
    </Circle>

    <Square id="sqr1">
      <color>yellow</color>
      <size>large</size>
    </Square>
  </Shapes>

    <Rectangle id="rec1">
      <color>blue</color>
      <size>medium</size>
    </Rectangle>
    <Circle id="cir1">
      <color>green</color>
      <size>small</size>
    </Circle>
    <Square id="sqr1">
      <color>yellow</color>
      <size>large</size>
    </Square>

  <Device>
    <Name>peg</Name>
    <type>X11</type>
  </Device>
  <Utilities>
    <Software>QT</Software>
    <Platform>Linux</Platform>
  </Utilities>
</Screen>
```

Is there a simple XSLT code I can use, or is there any modification in my xslt I can apply to get the output?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <Shapes>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Shapes/*"/>
      </Shapes>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[name()!='Shapes']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The idea is to process all the sub-elements of `Shapes` separately in one go, and then copy the rest.

Comment: Wow...The answer is so much simplified and elegant than any other potential answers I saw on net, and it works perfectly. No use of Keys/recursive previous or next sibling call. It was really helpful. Thanks a lot. (Cannot vote up yet, as I am fairly new to this site)

Comment: Thanks, glad you liked it

Comment: I tried to do same, but it copied everything from source to ouput

Comment: Probably `<xsl:copy-of select="Shapes/*"/>` is not matching anything - wrong element name, or maybe the source XML uses a namespace