# Using XSLT to rearrange/merge nodes of SVG file

Tags: xml, xslt, svg, matplotlib

I'm trying generate some svg images with matplotlib and embed them in both html and pdf reports. I've encountered [this bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92254) in `WebKit`, which my application uses, and another rendering bug in Adobe Acrobat. Both problems are caused by `matplotlib` placing `<clipPath>` elements at the end of the svg files.

To work around both bugs I want to use XSLT to merge all `<defs>` nodes into a single node at the start of the file

**Example svg**

```
<svg height="288pt" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 576 288" width="576pt" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <style type="text/css">
            *{stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:100000;}
        </style>
    </defs>
    <g id="figure_1">
        ...

    </g>
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="p8596dc1504">
            <rect height="230.5245" width="211.84" x="339.7475" y="28.90175"/>
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="p9534ff1f4d">
            <rect height="230.5245" width="211.84" x="66.534375" y="28.90175"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

**Desired output**

```
<svg height="288pt" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 576 288" width="576pt" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <style type="text/css">
            *{stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:100000;}
        </style>
        <clipPath id="p8596dc1504">
            <rect height="230.5245" width="211.84" x="339.7475" y="28.90175"/>
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="p9534ff1f4d">
            <rect height="230.5245" width="211.84" x="66.534375" y="28.90175"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g id="figure_1">
        ...

    </g>
</svg>
```

This is the current XSLT I have. The code removes the `<defs>` sections correctly, but all I get at the start of the document is `<defs xmlns=""/>` with no children.

**xsl file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <defs>
                <xsl:copy-of select="/svg/defs/*"/>
            </defs>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[name()!='defs']"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Ouput**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs xmlns=""/>
    <g id="figure_1">
        ...

    </g>
</svg>
```

I'm still trying to wrap my head around XSLT. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your stylesheet does not take into consideration the *namespace* used by the source XML.

Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <defs>
                <xsl:copy-of select="/svg:svg/svg:defs/*"/>
            </defs>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::svg:defs)]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Perfect, this does what I want! A comment in the [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18515711/3419537) I based my code on mentioned namespaces but I wasn't sure how to take them into account

Comment: @Parfait Good point. It wasn't in the original code, and one tends to focus on the main problem and overlook the rest. Now added.